# Extract details in multiple image filenames in Python and add them as labels for a dataset

Tags: python, extract, filenames

I have a folder containing 1300 .JPEG files all of which have filenames in a specific order.

The order of each file name is category_count_randomString.JPEG. To give an example, below is one image from the folder:

`13_2_5jdf.JPEG` where 13 is the category, 2 is the count of that category in the image, followed by the random string.

I'd like to be able to:

1. extract both the category from each filename and assign them as labels (to then build a CNN model) and
2. extract the count of the category from each filename and also assign them to a vector/array.

For now, I've just loaded the images (not yet as an array) using the glob function.

```
import glob

data = '/Users/Data'

images = glob.glob(data+'/*.JPEG')
```

I'm new to coding and so I'm looking for someone to be able to provide 'idiot-proof' lines of coding that I can just incorporate into my notebook to make this work.

Comment: How would you like to load the images in the end. A numpy array?

Comment: You can use `.split('_')` on the filenames to split them by the underscore---this will give you an array of three strings with the stuff that the underscores split.

Comment: e.g. `category, count, end = '13_2_5jdf.JPEG'.split('_')` will set `category = '13'`, `count = '2'`, and `end = '5jdf.JPEG'`. You can also look into the `os.path` module to split the JPEG extension off (if you want) and also to split the path and remove the preceding folder from the path string.

Comment: @adamconkey yes, as an numpy array. Here's the code I have to convert it before splitting it to x_train & y_train:
x = np.array([np.array(Image.open(fname)) for fname in images])

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds that's a good start. But how do i loop it over the 1300 images?

Comment: Use a `for` loop over the files in `glob` :). You don't need to write it in a list comprehension like you did with the training. Just build the lists manually and turn them to a numpy array later. For e.g., something like `for imagepath in images: cat, count, *end = imagepath.split('_'); categories.append(cat); counts.append(count)`. As stated before you'd also need an `os.path.split()` in there to remove the preceding directories so you only have the filename left before you split. Also the values will all be strings so you'd need to cast them to integers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `os` to get a list of all your files in your data directory and the `split` command to get at the information in your filename:

```
import os

data_path = "/Users/Data"

categories = []
counts = []
rand_strs = []

for img_filename in os.listdir(data_path):
    if img_filename.endswith(".JPEG"):
        category, count, rand_str = img_filename.split('.')[0].split('_')
        categories.append(category)
        counts.append(int(count))
        rand_strs.append(rand_str)
```

Each list is then indexed the same, so for example if you wanted to know how many counts you have for category 13, you can do

```
category_idx = categories.index('13')
print "Category %s has %d elements" % (categories[category_idx], counts[category_idx])
```

Comment: appreciate the help! So i pasted the entire code and get an error "not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)" at the first line right after the 'for' command. Do you know what this is about? Sorry, i'm a complete noob at this.

Comment: If your file format is as you say CATEGORY_COUNT_RAND.jpeg, then the `split` on `'.'` should give a list of `['CATEGORY_COUNT_RAND', 'jpeg']`, then it takes the first element and splits on `'_'` which should give you a list of three elements: `['CATEGORY', 'COUNT', 'RAND']`

Comment: Do all of the files in that directory have this format? If not, then the code above will break. I can add a further check if at least all of your JPEG files in that directory satisfy this format.

Comment: it is exactly like that. all 1300 of them. but weirdly enough, i'm getting this error. do you know what could be causing this?

Comment: when i use the glob function with the .JPEG argument, it does show 1300 count. so they are all indeed as cat_count_rand.JPEG

Comment: Replace that line with `output = img_filename.split('.')[0].split('_')` and do a `print output` right after to see what you are getting from that command.

Comment: so i entered the following: for img_filename in os.listdir(data_path):
    output = img_filename.split('.')[0].split('_'). when i print the output, it only shows ['13', '3', '351b']

Comment: I added a check for JPEG extensions in the code, your output is as I would expect though so I don't know why it doesn't work, it should just assign each of those 3 elements in the list to the three variables taking the assignment.

Comment: cheers, mate! that did the trick. Just one last question. I wanted to understand as to why you only added the 'int' while appending counts & not for categories as well? is there any specific reason? wouldn't they both be integers?

Comment: I left it as a string to leave open the possibility that category may be a non-integer, it made sense that count should always be an int but maybe your category was something semantic. If they are all ints, you can just cast them to ints as well.

Comment: Adam, this was surely kind assistance. However, for this question, I'd suggest that insufficient effort was made in the question - it was a fairly brazen request for free work. Readers are broadly happy to help beginners here, but being new ought not confer the right to ask for free labour. The OP is a student, and has gone on to ask for new free work again, this time for a homework assignment (now rightfully closed). My worry is that he/she will not learn anything until they knuckle down and go through the hard path of learning for themselves.

Comment: @halfer fair enough, I agree with what you say, I just knew I could answer this question because I do this sort of thing all of the time.

Comment: Coolio. I should say the state of the SQL and regex tags is completely woeful - there are often high-rep users waiting to garner rep and quite willing to fail to teach question authors the value of effort and persistence.